# Como gravar dados no registro do Windows?

Tags: c++

Preciso gravar dados no registro do Windows em minha aplicação.
Como trabalhar com a manipulação de dados do registro do Windows usando C++? 
Qual é a maneira correta de se gravar novos dados no registro sem erros?

Comment: Dando uma fuçada no SO gringo encontrei estes posts: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34065/4178863 e http://stackoverflow.com/q/15084380/4178863. Também tem esse: http://www.tenouk.com/ModuleO1.html Se você acha que te ser posso criar uma resposta em cima delas.

Comment: Você está usando C++/CLI? Ou C++ normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escrevendo no registro do **Windows**

```
/* Namespaces */
using namespace System;
using namespace Microsoft::Win32;

    //Criando uma instância gravável da classe de RegistryKey 
    RegistryKey^ rk;
    rk = Registry::LocalMachine->OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\", true);

    //Criando sua subchave
    RegistryKey^ nk = rk->CreateSubKey("DWORD");

    //Adicionando novo valor a sua subkey
    String^ newValue = "NewValue";
    try
    {
        nk->SetValue("NewKey", newValue);
        nk->SetValue("NewKey2", 44);
    }
    catch (Exception^)
    {
        Console::WriteLine("Failed to set new values in 'NewRegKey'");
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }
```

Se estiver usando **Visual Studio** lembre de fazer as seguintes alterações:

**Configuration Properties** -> General

**Configuration Properties** -> C/C++ -> General

Altere **Common Language RunTime Support** para "**Common Language RunTime Support (/clr)**"

Lembre também de fazer as **validações** no código.

Answer (score 2):

Além das soluções já apresentadas, é possível utilizar algumas [**WinAPIs**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff818516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) que fornecem a você o acesso ao Registro e a manipulação do mesmo.

- [`RegOpenKeyEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724897(v=vs.85).aspx): Abre a chave especificada para leitura ou gravação.
- [`RegCreateKeyEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724844(v=vs.85).aspx): Cria uma chave no Registro, caso já exista, a função abrirá tal chave. Vale lembrar que é possível criar quatro chaves de modo hierárquico, especificando uma sequência ao parâmetro `lpSubKey`, algo assim *subkey1\subkey2\subkey3\subkey4*.
- [`RegDeleteKeyEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724847(v=vs.85).aspx): Exclui uma chave do Registro e seus valores. A chave excluída não é removida até que o último identificador da operação seja fechado.
- [`RegDeleteKeyValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724848(v=vs.85).aspx): Exclui a *subchave* e valor especificados.
- [`RegDeleteTree`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379776(v=vs.85).aspx): Exclui as *subchaves* e valores da chave especificada de forma **recursiva**.
- [`RegDeleteValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724851(v=vs.85).aspx): Exclui um valor nomeado, especificando a chave.
- [`RegSetKeyValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724921(v=vs.85).aspx): Utilizado para alterar o nome de um valor ou chave, ou modificar os dados de um valor.
- [`RegSetValueEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724923(v=vs.85).aspx): Altera os dados e [**tipo**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911(v=vs.85).aspx)(*REG_SZ*, *REG_MULTI_SZ*,..) de um valor especificado, indicando a chave.
- [`RegQueryValueEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911(v=vs.85).aspx): Recupera os dados e o tipo de um valor especificado, associado a uma chave de registro aberta.
- [`RegGetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724868(v=vs.85).aspx): Semelhante a função acima, porém, a diferença entre elas é que esta é mais apropriada para retornar valores de [terminação nula](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caractere_nulo)(*REG_SZ, REG_MULTI_SZ*, e *REG_EXPAND_SZ*) enquanto a outra função pode não armazenar adequadamente os caracteres nulos.

Essas devem ser as funções que devem te interessar, a lista completa de funções que envolvem o Registro, pode ser vista [**aqui**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

---

Veja um exemplo de uso da função [`RegSetValueEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724923(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
HKEY regKey;
std::wstring foo = TEXT("O dado a ser gravado aqui");

Result = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run"), 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &regKey);
if (Result == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    Result = RegSetValueEx( regKey, 
        TEXT("Nome do valor"), 
        0, 
        REG_SZ, 
        (const BYTE*)foo.c_str(), 
        ( foo.size() + 1 ) * sizeof( wchar_t ) );
    if (Result == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        std::cout << "Done!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como nunca usei, vou postar somente o que achei no site da MSDN.

> O código a seguir usa a chave `CurrentUser` para criar uma instância de
>   escrita da classe `RegistryKey`, correspondendo à chave do Software. O
>   método `CreateSubKey` é usado para criar uma nova chave e adicionar os pares
>   valor/chave.

```
// registry_read.cpp
// compile with: /clr
using namespace System;
using namespace Microsoft::Win32;

int main( )
{
   array<String^>^ key = Registry::CurrentUser->GetSubKeyNames( );

   Console::WriteLine("Subkeys within CurrentUser root key:");
   for (int i=0; i<key->Length; i++)
   {
      Console::WriteLine("   {0}", key[i]);
   }

   Console::WriteLine("Opening subkey 'Identities'...");
   RegistryKey^ rk = nullptr;
   rk = Registry::CurrentUser->OpenSubKey("Identities");
   if (rk==nullptr)
   {
      Console::WriteLine("Registry key not found - aborting");
      return -1;
   }

   Console::WriteLine("Key/value pairs within 'Identities' key:");
   array<String^>^ name = rk->GetValueNames( );
   for (int i=0; i<name->Length; i++)
   {
      String^ value = rk->GetValue(name[i])->ToString();
      Console::WriteLine("   {0} = {1}", name[i], value);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Fonte: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwt6b955.aspx